# How can I join a Stack Overflow chat again?

Tags: discussion, chat

I have been in the 'Android'-chat for some time, and because I did not follow completely the rules of the room, the access to the chat has been revoked. Without any warning...

However, I read the chat room rules, and I understand the reason for being kicked out of the room. But I have been kicked out for more than 24 hours, and when trying to rejoin this chat, my request is being dismissed. And I do now know how to contact the room admin.

Now is there a possibility to join this chat again? Is my revocation for the whole life? Is there some limit? Is there only one single person the admin of such a room? What can I do?

The room in question is: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android

Comment: Do you see the text at the bottom of the screen: "*Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here. See the faq for more information.*" ? If so, then you will have to convince someone who owns that room to let you back in...

Comment: But how can I ask the owner of the room? Is there a way to contact a person in SO?

Comment: From experience, I wouldn't ever want to be in any place that won't have me.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Yes, that is a good advice!

Answer (score 17):

I was the one who revoked your access therefore I want to respond:

You got access a while ago but this week you started to seek help, which is ok. The way you moved through your problems was kind of odd.

Every minute or so you presented another error, you stated that you see the error but there is no error.

You asked for examples for different things that could be found easily on the web. You then later read (finally!) some official documentation and still got it wrong (remember the "must not" vs "don't need to"?).

The complete behavior resulted in a situation where multiple regulars of the room already put you on their personal ignore list.

As a room owner I had the duty to protect the room and you qualified as a help vampire (which are not allowed per rule) even more with every minute you had access.

I would ask you to let things cool down until start of the next week. If you request access again than, I will grant it and you can get your second chance.

Comment: Ok agreed! Thanks for your reply on that. I have read the rules for the room in detail again, and I agree that I behaved oddly. I will not act as a 'help vampire' again. Wish you a good weekend...

Answer (score 9):

The room in  question is a "gallery" room, which means that the owner(s) of the room get to decide who can and can't participate.

At one point, it would seem, you had access to participate in the room. Your behaviour lost you that access. It's now up to the room owners to decide whether or not you'll get that access back.

If you want to contact them, your best bet is to find another room they chat in that isn't a gallery room, and ping them (`@name`) there to explain the situation. Pointing them to this post may help your case.

Comment: Did you see the star board?

Comment: The star board? The list of owners of that room?

Comment: @Alex http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34261404#34261404 It seems that they **really** don't want you in there... so I recommend that you move on to greener pastures.

Comment: I saw that comment. In my view it is inappropriate and not very nice. A person should be granted a second chance...

Comment: @Alex if you find something to be "not nice" and you feel that it goes against the SE "be nice" policy (which I'd probably agree with you on), feel free to flag it for moderator attention... but note that that will not get you back into the room and is likely to make them even less inclined to let you in there ever.

Comment: So a room owner can decide by himself to ban a person as he likes? Is that correct?

Comment: In a gallery room, yes. That's the only sort of area on the site where users can be limited from access by other basic users. Generally, that requires being a moderator or staff.

Comment: But what can I do the to move to 'greener pastures', as you put it? When can I try to request access again? I am especially afraid, that the moderator in question will INDEED ban me from the whole stackoverflow! Maybe he can't do that, but maybe he can. And I cannot risk that...

Comment: Moving to greener pastures means **find a different room**. Room owners are not moderators. That threat he made was baseless... no moderator is going to ban you from chat for repeatedly requesting access to a gallery room... that's not how it works. Also, you'll notice that his comment has been deleted now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1056/discussion-between-alex-and-catija).